# Multiple login system with the roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, authlogic

I am working on a Institute ERP(school based) like project. It has a three login's DeveloperAdmin ->  InstituteAdmin, Teacher and the Student. And each of the has their own Previliges. So, how do I complete this multiple login system. I have no clue where to start. My Institute Model looks like

```
 class Institute
       has_many :institute_admins
       has_many :students
       has_many :teacher
end
```

My InstituteAdmin model looks like

```
class InstituteAdmin
       belongs_to :institute
end
```

My Student model looks like

```
class Student
     belongs_to :institute
end
```

My Teacher model looks like

```
class Teacher
      belongs_to :institute
end
```

And the main thing is each Institution must have a seperate url like

for Institute one => www.localhost/institutes/1 (institute 1 login page),
for Institute two => www.localhost/institutes/2

Is there a gem to complete this type of multilevel login? how to achieve this?

I am new to rails, and I am struck with this for 2 weeks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use devise and the after_login redirection. You don't really need a separate login page for each institue, just redirect after login based on the user institute and role.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use multiple model for userbase, use Devise. Devise has builtin option for multiple model auth. Actually majority of the auth gem has this ability.

In Devise, generate multiple model auth:

```
rails generate devise InstituteAdmin
rails generate devise Student
rails generate devise Teacher
```

It'll generate seperate login forms/ routes for each user types. SO you can easily handle any of customization.

Comment: thanks babar , how to authenticate by users(student ,admin, teacher) via belongs_to:institution .